# What is the SQL dialect for Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: intellij-idea

In my `.idea` directory there is a file called `sqldialects` that contains the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="SqlDialectMappings">
    <file url="PROJECT" dialect="MySQL" />
  </component>
</project>
```

I never set this to `MySQL` so perhaps it is a default. I would like it to use Microsoft SQL Server for the dialect. I'm guessing it would just be `MsSQL` but I can't seem to find the official word on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this file the configuration from Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Languages & Frameworks | SQL Dialects settings page is saved. Check what you have set there for the **Project**.

By default there is no value set. The dialect for MS SQL Server would be the **SQL Server**.